# Fluctuation-dissipation in a quantum Ising Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, ising-model, fluctuation-dissipation

For the classical Ising model, the fluctuation-dissipation theorem tells us that the Magnetic susceptibility is proportional to the variance of the magnetization. Is there an equivalent relation for the quantum Ising model in transverse field?